# Auto-generated pages in Hugo

Tags: html, generator, middleman, hugo

Is it possible to auto-generate pages from a data file in Hugo, like in Middleman? I have a yaml file `cars.yml` which looks like this:

```
---
- name: "Ford"
  color: "blue"
- name: "Cadillac"
  color: "pink"
```

and would like to auto-generate a separate page for each car record in the datafile based on a predefined template. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of the [documentation](http://gohugo.io/extras/datafiles/), I achieved the MVP in the following steps:

1. Installed a test Hugo site, `hugo new site carsite`.
2. Root folder already had `/data/` folder, I created `cars` subfolder there.
3. `carsite/data/cars` will hold each car as a separate file. This differs from your original plan to put them in a list, but one-file per one-car approach is better (version control, maintenance, less error-prone because erroneous .yml will be flagged separately, not monolithic data file).
4. Create content files inside `/data/` folder:

   `ford.yml`:

   ```
   Name: "Ford"
   Color: "Blue"
   ```

   and

   `cadillac.yml`:

   ```
   Name: "Cadillac"
   Color: "Pink"
   ```
5. Create a partial to style the car listing:

   `carsite/themes/<your theme name>/layouts/partials/car_listing.html`

   ```
   <li>{{ .Name }} in {{ .Color }}</li>
   ```
6. Call the loop, or in Go terminology, *range data files* in the file, responsible for your chosen location. For example, let's output it on the main homepage, which is controlled by `carsite/themes/<theme name>/layouts/index.html`:

   ```
   ...(existing header.html partial and so on)...
   <ul>
   {{ range $.Site.Data.cars }}
   {{ partial "car_listing.html" . }}
   {{ end }}
   </ul>
   ...(existing footer.html partial and so on)...
   ```

Here's how it looks on mine ([ghostwriter](http://themes.gohugo.io/ghostwriter/) template):

[image: Hugo Data files-driven pages]

---

If you insist on housing all the files **within one data file**, that should be doable too, just query the data file and *range* it. Also, if you chose `yml` format, set the correct format [sequence](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) of your data file (your proposed data structure looks suspicious since the list is straight in the root, instead add a key, for example, `cars:` as per aforementioned YML spec):

`carsite/data/cars.yml`

```
cars:
    - Name: Ford
      Color: Blue
    - Name: Cadillac
      Color: Pink
```

Comment: Many thanks! Indeed, that should do the trick. I don't have a choice so I will have to transform first `cars.yml` into separate files or investigate the second solution.

Comment: @helcim, would you set the above answer as "accepted"?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but how is that "a separate page for each car record"? I mean, you just put all the cars in the main page. Is it possible to generate a separate page for each car?

Comment: @anula my thoughts exactly! This doesn't answer the question OP asked.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a simple JS-wrapper that generates pages from data in Hugo.
I'm currently using it to generate articles from YAML files.

[kidsil/hugo-data-to-pages](https://github.com/kidsil/hugo-data-to-pages)